# Generating HMAC using Java

Tags: java, authentication, hmac

Just wanted to ask if this is the write way to generate an HMAC using Java, and if it is not, then what is the right way?

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacAlgorithms;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class HMACGenerator {

    public static final String API_SECRET_CODE = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    
    public static String generateHMAC(String key, String message) {
    
        var keyBytes = key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final var hmacHelper = HmacUtils.getInitializedMac(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_512, keyBytes);
        final Hex hexHelper = new Hex();
        final var raw = hmacHelper.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final var hex = hexHelper.encode(raw);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(hex);
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's strange to hex-encode the hmac output and then base64 encode the hex.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Do you know how should I exactly do it, I'm kinda new to authentication

Comment: It's not harmful, I'm just concerned that it won't interoperate with whatever protocol/system you're planning to use it with.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Hmm I see, so what youre saying is that I should remove the base64 encoding ?

Comment: The output of `hmacHelper.doFinal(()` is a byte []. There's nothing wrong with a byte[], so you could just return a byte[]. However, if you need to store or transmit it as a String for some reason then you should encode it. base64 encoding is probably more commonly used than hex encoding because it's more efficient, so that's what I'd most likely use.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Hmm okay I see, and when I tried what you just said it worked and it produced the same output as the online generator I tested on. So thank you so much

Comment: With Java 7 or later, you can use [javax.crypto.Mac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html).

Comment: @AllenD.Ball: in fact at least back to 6, and I think also 5 but I no longer have a test system for that and my website bookmarks fail. OTOH it's generally unwise to use unsupported versions.

Comment: You are correct: Javadoc says since "1.4".